# Tomcat web sockets marshaling - sending a json \ object?

Tags: java, json, websocket, gson

Here is my servlet code:

```
@Override
    public void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Open Client.");
            this.myoutbound = outbound;

            outbound.writeTextMessage(CharBuffer.wrap("Web sockets rules!"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to send java object through the outbound? and receive on the client a json? (marashling json)
I would like it to happen automagically and not with explicit marshalling with jackson \ gson every read\ onmessage.

here is my client side code that receives strings currently:

```
ws.onmessage = function(message) {
    debugger;
    document.getElementById("chatlog").textContent += message.data + "\n";
};
```

Comment: Not sure. Have you considered using Apache Thrift? It's a binary protocol. Alternatively, it sounds like Java RMI is your only alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not about websocket, is just how to convert java objects to String. You can write your own converters or use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), there is a tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/). There are others like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).